# ¿Consultar datos atraves de una llave Foránea?

Tags: php, mysql

mi consulta es la siguiente. Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL Suponiendo que tengo la siguientes tablas dentro de mi base de datos, donde las flechas amarrillas que puse indican las llaves primarias y la verde indica la llave foránea.

Necesito consultar el Nick de la tabla USER partiendo desde una consulta a la tabla POST, para poder juntar todo dentro de un Array, el cual va a contener toda la información extraída de la tabla POST y el NICK extraído de la tabla USER.

Utilizar el siguiente código me funciona, el problema es que me une TODOS los datos de la tabla USER (Lo cual no quiero, ya que me trae datos sensibles como la contraseña al Array)

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN post ON usuarios.id = post.idUser'); 
$statement->execute(array());
$post = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Estuve leyendo bastante ya que no manejo tanto SQL y fue la solución con la que di, pero no encontré algún recurso para implementar lo que digo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, la comparto por si alguien tiene el mismo problema. Para encontrarla me tuve que ver un curso de SQL en el cual daban justo un ejemplo similar.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT post.titulo, firma, post.descripcion, post.photoPrev FROM post INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = post.idUser'); 
$statement->execute(array());
```

Se pueden seleccionar las columnas moviendose desde la Tabla principal hacia la secundaria con el nombre de la tabla continuado por un "." (punto).

Al no saber esto mi sentencia fallaba al probar cosas similares. Firma al ser de la tabla principal no lleva post + "." (Firma es una columna que no puse en el ejemplo, pero seria lo mismo con email).

Comment: Aunque funcione ahora, tu consulta SQL no es conforme a las buenas prácticas. En consultas en las que intervienen varias tablas, debes poner siempre a qué tabla pertenece cada columna, así evitas un eventual error cuando una columna se llame igual en distintas tablas y das claridad al código, sabiendo siempre de dónde viene cada columna. Por tanto, si `firma` es una columna de `usuarios`, deberías ponerla así en el `SELECT`
: `usuarios.firma`.

Comment: En cuanto a la contraseña, considera guardar un hash de la misma, no la contraseña en bruto. Si guardas un hash, eso es lo que van a obtener en caso de que accedan a esos datos, pero será harto difícil descifrarlo para obtener la contraseña real. [Revisa aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) para más detalles.

Comment: Buen dato el primero. 
Con respecto al segundo. Si, es mero ejemplo, uso sha256. Gracias por el consejo igual. Se aprecia!